# python ssl error violation of protocols

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, https

I'm trying to use python to login and download some files, using the code:

```
import sys
import urllib
import urllib2
import httplib, ssl, socket
class HTTPSConnectionV3(httplib.HTTPSConnection):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        httplib.HTTPSConnection.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def connect(self):
        sock = socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port), self.timeout)
        if self._tunnel_host:
            self.sock = sock
            self._tunnel()
        try:
            self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3)
        except ssl.SSLError, e:
            print("Trying SSLv3.")
            #self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
            self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)

class HTTPSHandlerV3(urllib2.HTTPSHandler):
    def https_open(self, req):
        return self.do_open(HTTPSConnectionV3, req)
# install opener
urllib2.install_opener(urllib2.build_opener(HTTPSHandlerV3()))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ##fill the login form
    query={}
    query['username']='USER'
    query['password']='007'
    query['submit']='Submit'
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
                    print >> sys.stderr, "missing date"
                    sys.exit()
    #submit the form
    #http_req = urllib2.Request(url='https://www.connect2nse.com/iislNet', data=urllib.urlencode(query))
    http_req = urllib2.Request(url='https://www.connect2nse.com/iislNet/Login.jsp', data=urllib.urlencode(query))
    #http_req = urllib2.Request(url='https://www.connect2nse.com/iislNet/index.html', data=urllib.urlencode(query))
    webpage = urllib2.urlopen(http_req)
    webpage_headers = webpage.info()
    #extract the cookie
    cookie = webpage_headers['Set-Cookie'].split(';', 1)[0]
    print >> sys.stderr, "Set-Cookie:", cookie
    http_req = urllib2.Request(url='https://connect2nse.com/iislNet/MY.jsp', headers={'Cookie': cookie})
    webpage = urllib2.urlopen(http_req)
```

I get the following error

```
Trying SSLv3.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MYSCRIPT.py", line 51, in <module>
    webpage = urllib2.urlopen(http_req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 418, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "MYSCRIPT.py", line 27, in https_open
    return self.do_open(HTTPSConnectionV3, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1177, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 8] _ssl.c:504: EOF occurred in violation of protocol>
```

Although this was working fine till last month but now it gives the above error

I have already tried [This link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116020/python-https-requests-urllib2-to-some-sites-fail-on-ubuntu-12-04-without-proxy) but to no avail.
Using the requests in python I use 
r = requests.get('https://www.connect2nse.com/iislNet/Login.jsp', auth=('USER', '007')) 
r.status_code
401
But I'm not sure how to proceed using requests also.
Trying @Antti Haapala's solution doesnt work for me, tried it on 2.7.3&6

```
try: 
# self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23) 
self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1) 
except ssl.SSLError, e: 
print("Trying SSLv3.",e) 
# self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file, ssl_version=5) 
self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
```

TLSv1 and SSLv23 both give similar errors.

```
error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure' and
error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure'
```

@J.F. Sebastian , thanks but I'm 100% sure that login and password are correct, because I use the same while using in chrome. When I use TLSv1_2, I get the below error

```
 python MYSCRIPT.py 090315
Trying SSLv3.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MYSCRIPT.py", line 51, in <module>
    webpage = urllib2.urlopen(http_req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 418, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "MYSCRIPT.py", line 27, in https_open
    return self.do_open(HTTPSConnectionV3, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1174, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.get_selector(), req.data, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 958, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 992, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 954, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 814, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 776, in send
    self.connect()
  File "MYSCRIPT.py", line 22, in connect
    self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2'
```

The site published a notification of compatible  browser settings, after which the script started malfunctioning [this link shows compatibility, you need to click on NEW SSL DOC](https://connect2nse.com)

Comment: 401 http error means `Unauthorized` e.g., your login,password are incorrect i.e., there is no ssl error if you use `requests` here.

Comment: `openssl s_client -connect www.connect2nse.com:443 -tls1` ends prematurely <-- notice TLS 1.0 is forced. `openssl s_client -connect www.connect2nse.com:443 -tls1_2` makes the connection (though there is *self signed certificate in certificate chain* -- MITM attack is possible!). Try `ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2`

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian , thanks but I'm 100% sure that login and password are correct, because I use the same while using in chrome. When I use TLSv1_2, I get the below error (in my next comment)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian have added the details to the question. Thanks

Comment: [The constant is available only since Python 2.7.9 (recent)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2) (try to pass its numerical value `5`) or install 2.7.9 (you could use `pythonz` for that).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I tried `self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file, ssl_version=5)`    File "MYSCRIPT.py", line 27, in https_open
    return self.do_open(HTTPSConnectionV3, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1177, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error _ssl.c:316: Invalid SSL protocol variant specified.>

Answer (score 5):

Your code forces the connection to use SSL 3 protocol always, SSL 3 has been superseded in **the last millennium** by TLSv1.

In Pythons < 2.7.9 (2.7.8), you should choose `ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23`, which will support the highest possible TLS number supported by the OpenSSL library. It specifically in current OpenSSL versions means that `SSLv3`, `TLSv1`, `TLSv1.1`, and `TLSv1.2` **are** supported. Unlike the flag says, **SSLv2 will not be accepted** with recent versions of OpenSSL.

Thus we get:

```
def connect(self):
    sock = socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port), self.timeout)
    if self._tunnel_host:
        self.sock = sock
        self._tunnel()

    self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file,
                                ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
```

---

If `requests` connects, then you might want to use that instead. Your authorization should be sent as form values, and as a [POST request](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests):

```
data = {}
data['username']='USER'
data['password']='007'
data['submit']='Submit'
r = requests.post("https://www.connect2nse.com/iislNet/Login.jsp", data=data)
```

---

`ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2` appeared in Python 2.7.9 and 3.4, but is also available some backports even before that version number.

However, if `PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2` is **not** in `ssl` module, it also means that **TLS 1.2 only** cannot be used in Python even with the hardcoded protocol constant (5) -  The [reason is quite obvious from the `_ssl` source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2b4a04c3681b/Modules/_ssl.c#l1993) - the integer is only meaningful to the Python extension module, and it is used to choose the actual constructor method.

---

In Python 2.7.9 there will be a [SSLContext](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#ssl-contexts) object that can be used to [set flags on for SSL socket creation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#protocol-versions); in there one can at least try to monkey_patch to be future proof, but it is not possible with versions that do not also have the TLSv1.2 patch.

An example code on 2.7.9 on how to disable SSL 2 and 3, TLSv1.0, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2, forcing to use *the hypothetical TLSv1.3(?)*:

```
ssl_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
ssl_sock.context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_SSLv2 | ssl.OP_NO_SSLv3 \
   | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_2
```